# RealTime shown variables as JSON string changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Good evening,

I'm working on a personal project and it's going well. But an idea came up in my mind.

Is there a way to automatically refresh variables value as a JSON string changes (using jQuery / JavaScript?

EXAMPLE: starting JSON

```
data = { "time": "01:28" }
```

after a database check the string will be changed

```
data = { "time": "01:29" }
```

How can an element in the page always show the updated value without having to re-write

```
$('#some_id').text(data.time);
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "having to re-write?" Do you want both values to be displayed? It seems like you could just add the new value to an array (or array of objects) and read it out

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning to a variable, try calling a function instead:

```js
const data = (() => {
  let obj;
  function updateView(text) {
    $('#some_id').text(text);
  }
  return {
    setData: function(newObj) {
      obj = newObj;
      updateView(JSON.stringify(newObj));
    },
    getData: () => obj,
  };
})();
data.setData({ "time": "01:28" });
setTimeout(() => data.setData({ "time": "01:29" }), 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='some_id'></div>
```